# (Rails + Redmine) Display tab in the top menu depending upon user role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-api

I am working on Redmine 1.4.x. I have two roles: client and employee. To separate the roles I have added `is_client` boolean attribute to the database. Here is the use case:

```
if is_client?
  puts "it is client"
else
  puts "it is employee"
end
```

Now depending upon this role I have to display **Portal** tab in the top menu. To achieve this I tried the following:

```
Redmine::MenuManager.map :top_menu do |menu|
   menu.push :portal, "#", :html => {:id => "emp_portal", :onclick => "OpenEmployeePortal()"} , :if => (Proc.new { User.current.is_client? } && Proc.new { User.current.logged? })
end
```

But I couldn't succeed. It is showing the portal tab for both roles.

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Redmine::MenuManager.map :top_menu do |menu|
   menu.push :portal, "#", :html => {:id => "emp_portal", :onclick => "OpenEmployeePortal()"} , :if => (Proc.new { User.current.is_client? && User.current.logged? })
end
```